# Safari issue with :checked selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari, cross-browser

To select one or series of selected checkbox I'm using

**Script**

```
    function getCount(){
        var selectedCheckboxes = $('#container input[type=checkbox]:checked');
        var selectedCount = selectedCheckboxes.length;
        $('#selectedItems').val(selectedCount);
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    /*50 rows like top row*/
<table>
<input id="selectedItems" type="text" readonly />
<a onclick="getCount();">Get Count</a>
</div>
```

this code works perfectly in almost all browsers such as : **Chrome, Firefox, IE, Edge**, but both Windows and Mac versions of **Safari** has problem with **:checked**

Does anybody has a clue on this weird issue?

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about the Windows version of Safari since it's no longer updated (the last version being [5.1.7, apparently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history)). The failure of MacOS version, though, is a surprise; out of curiosity does `document.querySelectorAll('input:checked').length` return anything besides an error? If it's genuinely the `:checked` part of the jQuery selector that's failing it should still return an error.

Comment: Can you check developer tools for errors?

Comment: @DavidThomas I cannot understand what is the difference? but *interstingly* your javascript query returns the correct value, can you explain your suggestion in a reply so that I can mark it as answer and close this issue for newcomers

Comment: If `querySelectorAll` works, i guess even jQuery selector should work. Try with simple `$('input:checked')`. Please show the rendered html. Better if you show the rendered html in both types of browsers.

Comment: While it's a workaround, I don't know *why* it works when jQuery *should* be passing the work of selection to `document.querySelectorAll()` anyway. Can you show your HTML and enough of your script to verify that what *should* be happening is happening? If not then you're free to post that workaround as an answer yourself, for my part I don't like posting answers that I can't verify (I don't own any Apple systems, other than a damaged iPad that's currently unusable).

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks for your workaround, I updated my question and provide more details, hope it represents more details

Comment: Try using a `button` instead of anchor `a`